# Scroll Position GUI with Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, user-interface

I have a text chat application developed in Silverlight. The app is polling the server every 2 seconds for incoming data and thats when I set my scroll bar's position to the last message.

There is something fishy with the scroll bar's position which I cannot understand. I have hosted the app here, http://bit.ly/h2yopt

Can you please help me work out the scroll position.

PS: Please try entering the message and then move the scroll bar.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, can you specify what behavior you want from the scroll bar because what happens now is that even if you are scrolling up, the scroll position is moved to the bottom every time you poll the server. Is that the "fishy" behavior you are referring to? If so, then it is a choice as to whether you want that behavior or if you want a different behavior.

Comment: My suggestion would be to avoid scrolling automatically if the scroll position is not already at the bottom.

Comment: @Johannes, yes, that is the fishy behavior. I want the scroll position to be at the bottom by default and the user should be able to scroll it up and down or whatever the case may be. Now, the default scroll position in SL is up.

Comment: I would put all my messages in ObservableCollection and observe it for changes, as soon as new items was added (from a server or by a user or from wherever), you scroll down.

Comment: @Vitalij this is a group chat, so almost every 2 seconds, I get a lot of messages, so eventually I would have to set it to the bottom position every 2 seconds. This makes it impossible for others to see the earlier messages. I want something like GTalk does, the chat box and teh scrollbar are not related to each other, but the default position of the scroll bar is down.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the scrollbar is moved down every 2 seconds. Show us the code.

Comment: ya, it is moved down every 2 seconds when I poll the server. What part of the code would you like to see?

Comment: You just confirmed the effect I am seeing. So I don't need to see any code. Just determine the effect you want and code it. You could add some code that only scrolls down when the scroll position is all the way down.

Comment: I want the scroll position to behave the way the scrolling happens in GTalk. The user should be able to scroll it up/down but its default position should be down.

Comment: That is what my suggestions does. In the sync to the server, first check if the current position is all the way down. Then download new messages. If the the scroll position was all the way down, scroll down, if not, do not scroll at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a text chat application
>   developed in Silverlight. The app is
>   polling the server every 2 seconds for
>   incoming data and thats when I set my
>   scroll bar's position to the last
>   message.

Then don't adjust the scrolling every time you poll, adjust it only when you need to like maybe when you enter a message yourself or whenever. Also, is the list DataBound? I think you would have more control if you do this control level.

Hope this helps.